# Table and column naming convention Postgres Dart-Aqueduct

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, aqueduct

I'm having a conflict in defining the way we name tables and columns.
I'm using Postgres and Aqueduct framework in Dart.

As I know Postgres doesn't like capitals. So the preferred method is for example `changed_by`. Dart prefers lowerCamelCase, for example `changedBy`.

Till now we use lowercase in Postgres `changedby` and lowerCamelCase in Dart `changedBy`.

Because Postgres ignores capitals as long as you don't use double quotes `"changedBy"` this works fine.

The problem is the readability in Postgres.
So what is the best practice?

Comment: "*So what is the best practice?*" - use `snake_case`. Does your obfuscation layer really not let you choose the names you want?